# UIBarbutton on ViewController

Tags: iphone, user-interface

I'm trying to initialize a barbutton item on my ViewController for an i-phone app.

in implementation:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
 UIButton *TakePhoto = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[TakePhoto setTitle:@"Take Photo" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
TakePhoto.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12.0f];
[TakePhoto.layer setCornerRadius:4.0f];
[TakePhoto.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
[TakePhoto.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
TakePhoto.frame=CGRectMake(200, 100.0, 60.0, 30.0);
[TakePhoto addTarget:self action:@selector(takePicture) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem* barbutton= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:TakePhoto];
}
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I don't see a red barbutton item on my tab bar

Answer (score 1):

you have to set this button where you want to display it for e.g.

> ```
> self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barbutton
> ```

Comment: Does navigationItem have to be initialised in .h?